# Matlab 2011b - Error using mex

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, compiler-errors, mex

I install libviso2 library on ubuntu. It contains a folder named matlab. There are many `.m` demo files and cpp under matlab. To run these demos, I installed Matlab. `matlab.ex`e is under `/home/user/MATLAB/bin/`.

`.m` files are under `/home/user/Documents/libviso2/matlab`.

Readme of libviso2 says that

> If you want to use libviso directly from MATLAB you can easily do this
>   by using the MATLAB wrappers provided. They also include some demo
>   files for testing. In the MATLAB directory of libviso, simply run
>   'make.m' to generate the mex wrappers. (Run mex -setup before to
>   choose your desired compiler)

I start matlab using `~/MATLAB/bin$ ./matlab` ,I open `make.m` file on matlab and press tun button, it says that

```
make
Building wrappers ...
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.6.3-1ubuntu5)".  The version
         currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
         For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/
      mex:  matcherMex.cpp  not a normal file or does not exist.
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
Error in make (line 5)
mex('matcherMex.cpp','../src/matcher.cpp','../src/filter.cpp','../src/triangle.cpp','../src/matrix.cpp','-I../src','CXXFLAGS=-msse3
-fPIC');
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if you ls before mex, is mexMatcher.cpp there?

Comment: matcherMex.cpp is there. I try to run `mex('matcherMex.cpp','.....,'CXXFLAGS=-msse3 -fPIC');
`